# Where to install SSL?

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean

This is a really stupid question, but im confused about this. I own a domain and i have pointed my traffic from the domain to my digital ocean server, running a node.js app.

My question is where do i install the SSL-Cert? On the server running the app or at the domain(cpanel)? If that makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: install on your server... this is no dumb question but next time make a research before asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On the server running the app" is the correct answer.

How you do that depends on your server I guess. For IIS you'll want to follow something like this:

https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1226960-install-certificate---internet-information-services-iis-7